# Sturm-Liouville problem: where did we use $p' \in C(\bar{I})$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I'm reading section *8.4 Some Examples of Boundary Value Problems* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*.

> **Example 2** (Sturm-Liouville problem). Consider the problem
> $$
> (18) \quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> -\left(p u^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+q u=f \quad \text { on } I=(0,1), \\
> u(0)=u(1)=0,
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> where $p \in C^1(\bar{I}), q \in C(\bar{I})$, and $f \in L^2(I)$ are given with
> $$
> p(x) \geq \alpha>0 \quad \forall x \in I .
> $$
> If $u$ is a classical solution of (18) we have
> $$
> \int_I p u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I q u v=\int_I f v \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(I) .
> $$
> We use $H_0^1(I)$ as our function space and
> $$
> a(u, v)=\int_I p u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I q u v
> \tag{$*$}
> $$
> as symmetric continuous bilinear form on $H_0^1$. If $q \geq 0$ on $I$ this form is coercive by Poincaré's inequality (Proposition 8.13). Thus, by Lax-Milgram's theorem, there exists a unique $u \in H_0^1$ such that
> $$
> (19) \quad
> a(u, v)=\int_I f v \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(I).
> $$
> Moreover, $u$ is obtained by
> $$
> \min _{v \in H_0^1(I)}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \int_I\left [ p (v^{\prime})^2+q v^2\right]-\int_I f v\right\} .
> $$
> It is clear from (19) that $p u^{\prime} \in H^1$; thus (by Corollary 8.10) $u^{\prime}=(1 / p)\left(p u^{\prime}\right) \in H^1$ and hence $u \in H^2$. Finally, if $f \in C(\bar{I})$, then $p u^{\prime} \in C^1(\bar{I})$, and so $u^{\prime} \in C^1(\bar{I})$, i.e., $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$. Step D carries over and we conclude that $u$ is a classical solution of (18).

We have $q \in C(\bar{I})$ implies $q \in L^k (I)$ for any $k \in [1, \infty]$. Then the integral $\int_I q u v$ in $(*)$ is well-defined. Similarly, $p \in C(\bar{I})$ implies the integral $\int_I p u' v'$ in $(*)$ is well-defined.

Could you explain where we use $p \in C^1(\bar{I})$ or more precisely $p' \in C(\bar{I})$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the hypothesis $p' \in C(\bar{I})$ in

> thus (by Corollary 8.10) $u^{\prime}=(1 / p)\left(p u^{\prime}\right) \in H^1$.

Recall that

> **Corollary 8.10** Let $I$ be a (possibly unbounded) open interval of $\mathbb R$. Let $u, v \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $1 \leq p \leq$ $\infty$. Then $u v \in W^{1, p}(I)$ and  $(u v)^{\prime}=u^{\prime} v+u v^{\prime}$. Furthermore, the formula for integration by parts holds:
> $$
> \int_y^x u^{\prime} v=u(x) v(x)-u(y) v(y)-\int_y^x u v^{\prime} \quad \forall x, y \in \bar{I} .
> $$

To apply **Corollary 8.10**, we need $1/p \in H^1(I)$. Hence the condition $p' \in C(\bar{I})$ is needed.