# The existence of a solution to $-(pU')' + qU = f$ on $(0, 1)$ with boundary condition $U(1) = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Assume that $p \in C^1(\bar I)$ and $q \in$ $C(\bar I)$ such that $p(x) \geq \alpha>0$ and $q(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \bar I$. Let $f \in L^2 (I)$.

In the solution for exercise 8.21.2 in his book *Functional Analysis*, Brezis considers the equation
$$
(*) \quad
\begin{cases}
-(pU')' + qU &= f \text{ on } I, \\
U(1) &= 0.
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to use Lax–Milgram theorem but could not obtain the continuity and coercivity of the bilinear form $a$. Could you elaborate on how to prove the existence of above ODE?

---

**My attempt** If $U$ is a classical solution of $(*)$, then
$$
-\int_I (pU')' V + \int_I qUV= \int_I fV,
\quad \forall V \in H^1(I).
$$

Let $\mathcal K := \{V \in H^1 (I): V(1)=0\}$. Then $V$ is a closed subspace of $H^1 (I)$. By integration by parts, for each $V \in \mathcal K$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I (pU')' V &= (pU' V) (1) - (pU' V) (0) - \int_I pU'V' \\
&= -(pU' V) (0) - \int_I pU'V'.
\end{align*}
$$

Then $U$ satisfies
$$
(pU' V) (0) + \int_I [qUV + pU'V']= \int_I fV,
\quad \forall V \in \mathcal K.
$$

We define a (non-symmetric) bilinear form $a$ on $\mathcal K$ by
$$
a(U, V) := (pU' V) (0) + \int_I [qUV + pU'V'].
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fix an arbitrary $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and consider
$$
(1) \quad
\begin{cases}
-(pU')' + qU &= f \text{ on } I, \\
U(0) &= \alpha, \\
U(1) &= 0.
\end{cases}
$$

We fix $g \in C^\infty (\bar I)$ such that $g(0) = \alpha$ and $g(1)=0$. Then $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
(2) \quad
\begin{cases}
-(p(W+g)')' + q(W+g) &= f \text{ on } I, \\
W(0) &= 0, \\
W(1) &= 0,
\end{cases}
$$

which is in turn equivalent to
$$
(3) \quad
\begin{cases}
-(pW')' + qW &= h:=f+(pg')'-qg \text{ on } I, \\
W(0) &= 0, \\
W(1) &= 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Given the hypothesis about $p$ and $q$, we can apply Lax-Milgram theorem (as in your [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767545/sturm-liouville-problem-where-did-we-use-p-in-c-bari?rq=1)) to get the existence of the unique solution $\bar W \in H^2 (I)$ to $(3)$. We get back the unique solution $\bar U \in H^2 (I)$ to $(1)$ by setting $\bar U :=\bar W + g$.